# Gel all model attributes of a class in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reflection, typescript

I have the following TypeScript class:

```
export class City {
  name: string;
  fullName: string;
  country: string;
  countryCode: string;
  center: GeoPoint;
}
```

I need a way of getting all model attributes in runtime. For example:

```
static init(obj): City {

    let city = new City();

    for (var i in obj) {
      if (i == "exists in City model") {
        city[i] = obj[i];
      }
    }
}
```

is there a simple way of doing this in TypeScript? I don't want to be required to maintain an array of all model attributes names to check this.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't provide any extra infomations, so you are going to do it in js way.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the generated output from TypeScript compiler on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org) it doesn't set any class properties that don't have a default value. So a possible way could be initializing all of them with `null`:

```
export class City {
    name: string = null;
    fullName: string = null;
    country: string = null;
    countryCode: string = null;
    center: string = null;

    ...
}
```

Then checking whether the object property exists on the object with: `typeof`. Your updated code:

```
export class City {
  name: string = null;
  fullName: string = null;
  country: string = null;
  countryCode: string = null;
  center: string = null;

  static init(obj): City {

    let city = new City();

    for (var i in obj) {
      if (typeof(obj[i]) !== 'undefined') {
        city[i] = obj[i];
      }
    }
    return city
  }
}

var c = City.init({
  name: 'aaa',
  country: 'bbb',
});

console.log(c);
```

Print output when compiled and run with `node`:

```
City {
  name: 'aaa',
  fullName: null,
  country: 'bbb',
  countryCode: null,
  center: null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out an enhanced version of the TypeScript compiler that allows you to retrieve classes/interfaces metadata (fields, methods, generic types, etc.) at runtime. For example, you can write:

```
export class City {
    name: string = null;
    fullName: string = null;
    country: string = null;
    countryCode: string = null;
    center: string = null;
}

function printMembers(clazz: Class) {
    let fields = clazz.members.filter(m => m.type.kind !== 'function'); //exclude methods.
    for(let field of fields) {
        let typeName = field.type.kind;
        if(typeName === 'class' || typeName === 'interface') {
            typeName = (<Class | Interface>field.type).name;
        }
        console.log(`Field ${field.name} of ${clazz.name} has type: ${typeName}`);
    }
}

printMembers(City.getClass());
```

and this is the output:

```
$ node main.js
Field name of City has type: string
Field fullName of City has type: string
Field country of City has type: string
Field countryCode of City has type: string
Field center of City has type: string
```

Then you can use `City` metadata in your `for` loop to check existence of values on a specific instance.

You can find all the details about my project [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflec-ts)